# React/redux: I have to reload page to delete

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So this has been a difficult thing to tackle. The issue I am having is I have to refresh the the page when I delete something. I was being told that I might not be updating the state correctly, and the state is being controlled through redux.

This is my Delete action from my reducer

```
case 'Delete_Recipe':
            
            const recipes = state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.id)
            return {...state, recipes}
```

And here is my delete action

```
export const deleteRecipe = (recipeId) =>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    return (dispatch) => {
        
        fetch(`${RECIPES_URL}/${recipeId}`,{method: 'DELETE'})
          .then(response =>{ return response.json()})
          .then(recipeId => { return dispatch({ type: 'Delete_Recipe', recipeId })});
         
         
          
      };
       
  }
```

I think this all that is needed let me know if you need anything else. But what else can I do to where I can delete without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, this line

```js
const recipes = state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.id)
```

should be:

```js
const recipes = state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.recipeId)
```

Comment: @Stitch Does `recipe.id` and `action.recipeId` have the same type?

Comment: This has been what I am having difficult confirming. I have the debugger on it

Comment: I don't think they are the same type

Comment: Then convert them to the same type...@Stitch

Comment: They were the same type. Sorry about the long response